# Add multiple classes with 1 button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add multiple classes to different items. I use this code:

```
    (function() {
    
      var button = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
      var box = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle2');
    
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
        box.classList.toggle('active');
    
      });
    
    })();

   <button class="menu-toggle menu-toggle2"></button>
   <div class="menu-mob"></div>
```

after click:

```
<button class="menu-toggle menu-toggle2 active"></button>
<div class="menu-mob"></div>
```

And after click, I want to add `activemenu` class to `mob-menu` class too.